# gridview cells merging and sum merged rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, merge

```
for (int rowIndex = GVDCNoConfirm.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
{
    GridViewRow currentRow = GVDCNoConfirm.Rows[rowIndex];
    GridViewRow previousRow = GVDCNoConfirm.Rows[rowIndex + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < currentRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (currentRow.Cells[i].Text == previousRow.Cells[i].Text)
        {
            if (previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan < 2)
                currentRow.Cells[i].RowSpan = 2;
            else
                currentRow.Cells[i].RowSpan = previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan + 1;
            previousRow.Cells[i].Visible = false;
        }
      if (row.Cells[6].Text == previousRow.Cells[6].Text)
                {
                    float currentvalue = 0;
                    currentvalue = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells[5].Text);
                    float previousvalue = currentvalue + Convert.ToSingle(previousRow.Cells[5].Text);
                    row.Cells[5].Text = Convert.ToString(previousvalue);
                    previousRow.Cells[j].Visible = false;
                }
    }
}
```

I have this code in RowDataBound for merging gridview rows. Its working fine But

```
         sno    name    amount   dcno    
          1     xxx     5000     888
                        2500     888
                        1000     1001
          2     yyy     5250     1002
                        2000      555
                        1250      555
```

In this grid I want to sum (5000+2500)=7500 i.e same dcno 888 and like that (2000+1250)=3250 i.e same dcno 555

So I need Out put like

```
         sno    name   amount   dcno
         1     xxx     7500     888
                       1000     1001
         2     yyy     5250    1002
                       3250     555
```

I tried like this but no use please any one help me.

Comment: In your example *dcno* for *amount = 2500* is not *888* but empty. Or do you mean, you want to merge rows with the same value and empty ones with the first(above) non empty one?

Answer (score 3):

You can chage your DataSource for a grouped one. For example:
Your current query looks like:

```
Items.Select(t => new {t.sno, t.name, t.amount, t.dcno})
```

And the new will be:

```
Items.Select(t => new {t.sno, t.name, t.amount, t.dcno})
     .GroupBy(t => new {t.sno, t.name, t.dcno})
     .Select(t => new {t.Key.sno, t.Key.name, t.Key.dcno, amount = t.Sum(a => a.amount)}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Exactly, LINQ is the easiest way to do this inside C#. Even without LINQ you will need to SUM the data BEFORE you bind it to the view. You could do this with a loop through the DataSet and some old fashioned coding... but why bother. LINQ is just too easy!

Answer (score 0):

Can not you prepare you source date before the databind? If I understand must be a 'group by' on dcno filed, right? In this case you can LINQ for the preparation of the data.

[group-by-sum-linq-to-sql-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672632/group-by-sum-linq-to-sql-in-c-sharp)